# Ansible : Return a attribute from list, with filter applied on another attribute

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I am getting the below dictionary from calling python library called from Ansible.

```
{
    "replication_detail": [
        {
            "name": "xxx.203.server:11111",
            "self": true,
            "state": 1,
            "stateStr": "PRIMARY",
            "syncSourceHost": "",
            "syncingTo": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "xxx.204.server:11111",
            "state": 2,
            "stateStr": "SECONDARY",
            "syncSourceHost": "xxx.203,server:11111",
            "syncingTo": "xxx.203,server:11111"
        },
        {
            "name": "xxx.205,server:11111"
            "state": 8,
            "stateStr": "(not reachable/healthy)",
            "syncSourceHost": "",
            "syncingTo": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I wanted to have a filter which look into another element which is "StateStr" should be in ["PRIMARY","SECONDARY"] and return the "name"

I tried match or equalto but they all take only one value.  Is there other any function which can look into multiple search values.

I am trying to get the data using map in single line rather than with_loop.

the code like 
"select name from replication_detail where sateStr in (PRIMARY, SECONDARY)"

replication_detail| stateStr in (PRIMARY, SECONDARY)) | map(attribute="name"|list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `selectattr` filter to filter a list of dictionaries by an attribute.  For example, if the data in your question is contained in a variable named `data`, then the following task:

```
    - debug:
        msg: "name: {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ data.replication_detail|selectattr('stateStr', 'match', 'SECONDARY|PRIMARY')|map(attribute='name')|list }}"
```

Would output:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=xxx.203.server:11111) => {
    "msg": "name: xxx.203.server:11111"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=xxx.204.server:11111) => {
    "msg": "name: xxx.204.server:11111"
}
```

Would output:

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. how to find elements does not match.

Comment: There is a `rejectattr` filter which does the opposite of `selectattr`.